# Why does this subquery of the same table in the outer query work as a valid comparison

Tags: sql

For all departments, I am trying to find the highest course number used by that department.  For practice, I am trying to achieve this using the ALL modifier rather than MAX().

I have found a solution, but I am not sure why this works.

```
SELECT department, coursenr 
FROM course U 
WHERE U.coursenr 
>= ALL (SELECT coursenr FROM course WHERE department = U.department)
```

Here is a picture of the table I am working with.

[image]

When I remove the alias 'U' from the outer query and change the subquery to read

```
SELECT coursenr FROM course WHERE department = department
```

The whole query no longer works correctly.  My question is, why does the whole query no longer work when I remove the 'U' alias from the outer query?  In other words, what exactly is the alias 'U' doing for me in this case?

Comment: it is a correlated subquery.  you are specifying which logical table the column is being read from.

Comment: But isn’t department always going to equal u.department?  That’s why I don’t understand what logical purpose it serves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your question is clarified in the comment:

> But isn’t department always going to equal u.department? 
>   That’s why I don’t understand what logical purpose it serves.

The answer is no.
In the subquery, `U.department` is the value of the column `department` of the table which is aliased as `U` and `department` is the value of the column `department` of the subquery.
 And these 2 values are compared against each other. 
This is why you need the alias. 
But if you remove `U` from `U.department`, this query:

```
SELECT coursenr FROM course WHERE department = department
```

returns all `coursenr` values from the table `course`, because:

```
department = department
```

is always `true`.
Then this:

```
SELECT department, coursenr 
FROM course U 
WHERE U.coursenr 
>= ALL <values of coursenr>
```

will return only the row with the maximum `coursenr` of the whole table (or more rows if there are more with this maximum value).

Answer (score 1):

you used Correlated Subqueries.SQL Correlated Subqueries are used to select data from a table referenced in the outer query. The subquery is known as a correlated because the subquery is related to the outer query. In this type of queries, a table alias (also called a correlation name) must be used to specify which table reference is to be used.
so here in your query

`WHERE department = U.department` `U` is the outer query refernece table alias name
as a result without U reference will be lost and query will not perform the expected behave that you need

Answer (score 1):

Your query is a corelated subquery as you want records which match some column of the outer query as in this case department be the matching column meaning selecting records row by row which match the departments  and whose row courseno is greater than all the subquery coursenos for the given row department.

But, I dont get the idea what are you actually trying to achieve. If I go by your actual question department wise max course no just use a group by

```
     SELECT department, max(courseno) 
      from table group by department
```